# How to use the results of a prior value-of expression to a new if-test expression

Tags: xml, xslt

My massive XML document has this format:

```
<zoo>
    <group name="A">
        <animal>Monkey</animal>
        <animal>Cat</animal>
        <animal>Horse</animal>
        <animal>Dog</animal>
    </group>
    <group name="B">
        <animal>Honey Badger</animal>
        <animal>Cat</animal>
    </group>
    <group name="C">
        <animal>Dog</animal>
        <animal>Pig</animal>
        <animal>Honey Badger</animal>
    </group>
</zoo>
```

The XSLT needs to produce two tables.

The first table prints without issue and in each row it shows one @name in the left column with a list of the animals related to that group in the right column for a total of three rows.

The requirements of the second table are more severe. For each row, the first column shows one non-repeating animal (meaning that although there are two cats in the whole XML document, it must only show one), and the entire column is in alphabetical order. So the left column looks like this (rows are numbered):

1.Cat
2.Dog
3.Honey Badger
4.Horse
5.Monkey
6.Pig

This part is actually achieved. The issue is the second column, which is supposed to show a list of all the group names that contain the animal in the left column, so the Cat row would show "A" and "B" on the right in a list, and the Dog row would show "A" and "C", etc.

I somehow need to use the result of the "value-of" expression that populates the left column in the "if test" expression that determines what goes in the right. At least, this is what I THINK I need to do. There's probably a much simpler way to get the result I want.

Here is the XSL of the second table:

```
 1.<table border="1" align="center">
 2.    <tr>
 3.        <th>ANIMAL</th>
 4.        <th>GROUPS CONTAINING THIS ANIMAL</th>
 5.    </tr>
 6.    <xsl:for-each select="zoo/group/animal">
 7.        <xsl:sort select="."/>
 8.        <xsl:if test="not(preceding::animal[. = current()/.])">
 9.            <tr>
10.                <td>
11.                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
12.                </td>
13.                <td>
14.                    <ul>
15.                        <xsl:for-each select="../..">
16.                            <xsl:for-each select="group">
17.                                <xsl:if test="animal = ???????">
18.                                    <li>
19.                                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
20.                                    </li>
21.                                </xsl:if>
22.                            </xsl:for-each>
23.                        </xsl:for-each>
24.                    </ul>
25.                </td>
26.            </tr>
27.        </xsl:if>
28.    </xsl:for-each>
29.</table>
```

My problem: how do I transfer the results of line 11 into the question marks of line 17 to make the if test execute correctly?

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html (assuming you're using XSLT 1.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After line 8, add

```
<xsl:variable name="current-animal" select="." />
```

And then line 17 (which is now 18) becomes:

```
   <xsl:if test="animal = $current-animal">
```

Disclaimer: I am answering based on the question in the "My problem" paragraph; I didn't read all the middle text of the whole question. (I'm not saying your whole question was too long or redundant; just that I'm hoping I can answer based on the final summary. If this answer doesn't work, and you tell me that, I'll try to go back to the question and give a better answer.)

Comment: THANK you for the fast response! It works perfectly!